# centering div on 4 other divs

Tags: html, css, centering

I know there are a lot of div centering questions but most only revolve that div and not surrounding divs...
I have 4 divs equal of width and height.
On top of that,  I would like to have another div but centered (vertical & horizontal) above those 4.
I came this far:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="logoWrapper"></div>
<div class="topleft" id="wrapper"></div>
<div class="topright" id="wrapper"></div>
<div class="bottomleft" id="wrapper"></div>
<div class="bottomright" id="wrapper"></div>
</div>

.logoWrapper {
width:270px;
height:150px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-75px 0 0 -135px;
}

#wrapper {
width: 49%;
height: 49%;
float: left;
background-color: #79be53;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 1%;
border-style: solid;
}
```

For some reason I dont understand yet this does not center the div...its a bit to the right of my screen! Or am I going crazy...?!

Comment: id's should be unique on a document, you have 4 wrapper id's

Comment: @Billy in his example, it does not really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you want something like this

[image]

Then do this change `position` to `relative` and adjust `margin` accordingly

```
.logoWrapper {
    width: 270px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: 0px 0 0 -135px;
    background: #FF0004;
}
```

As mentioned by @billy id needs to be unique

so change your code in to this

```
<div class="content">
<div class="logoWrapper"></div>
<div class="topleft" id="wrapper1"></div>
<div class="topright" id="wrapper2"></div>
<div class="bottomleft" id="wrapper3"></div>
<div class="bottomright" id="wrapper4"></div>
</div>
```

and css to this

```
#wrapper1,#wrapper2,#wrapper3,#wrapper4 {

}
```

> If you want your div like this

[image]

Then just add background color to `.logoWrapper`(Its transparent by default) its already in center. If its not in center for you just add unique id to those div's that might be causing issue

The easiest way to center div will be

```
.logoWrapper {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

No need to adjust margin this property is enough to center div.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/81cLt6t6/

This is how I centered the box

```
.logoWrapper {
width:270px;
background-color: red;    
height:150px;
position:absolute;
left: calc(50% - 135px);
top: calc(52% - 75px);
/*margin:-75px 0 0 -135px;*/
z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, now that i re-look at my code and the screen, I have a feeling I was just being paranoid and the div WAS cenetred....it just looks to be off for some reason, I think I should get my eyes checked haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ID`s are unique, so don't repeat them.

I'm not quiet sure what you are trying to achieve, but here is a snippet using [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```css
.content {
  position: relative
}
.logoWrapper {
  width: 270px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 135px);
  top: calc(50% + 135px);
  background: blue
}
.wrapper {
  width: 49%;
  height: 49%;
  min-height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #79be53;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 1%;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="logoWrapper"></div>
  <div class="topleftt wrapper"></div>
  <div class="topright wrapper"></div>
  <div class="bottomleft wrapper"></div>
  <div class="bottomright wrapper"></div>
</div>
```